# Eclipse internal web browser rendering incorrectly after OS system update

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, browser

I have successfully been using the eclipse Indigo internal browser to view my web apps. I'm playing around with the Spring petclinic application. After a recent OS X 10.7 update (to 10.7.4 from 10.7.3), the text boxes rendered inside of the internal web browser have black backgrounds and text can only been seen when highlighted.

I've tested my app with chrome, firefox, and safari on my mac and they all render correctly. The only change I can think of is the OS update. I've checked for updates to my browsers, OS, eclipse, and eclipse plugins.

I've googled extensively and see a lot of people complaining about the internal browser in general, but nothing recently. I have also found people asking how to swap out the renderer and have found posts saying that is no longer possible. The most interesting part about this is, if I launch Aptana Studio at the same time as my app is up, I can use the internal browser in Aptana and my app looks fine, just like it did last week.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Eclipe use [SWT Browser widget](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#whatisbrowser). Maybe you can be arranged by modifying the directory `.metadata` of your workspace. If you do not mind, you could delete it entirely and see if this works. Otherwise, you may need to switch to another version of Eclipse that supports the new browser.

Comment: That was a good idea, but it didn't work.

Comment: Congratulations, so far you're the first one I heard of using the internal Eclipse browser :-) In other words - is it worth debugging this problem if all 'real' browsers do work?

Comment: Yeah, it is worthwhile because I show people my screen while I'm making changes, and it is harder to follow if I have to change applications vs. just changing tabs.

Comment: I have the same problem, maybe it is better open an incident on the eclipse bugzilla .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eclipse on OS X uses the Standard Web Toolkit (SWT) Browser to render HTML documents.  The browser is based on webkit.  The symptom of black backgrounds in text and password input fields is a recorded bug that appears under OS X Lion (OS X 10.7): https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=86266.  You could jump through some hoops to replace the webkit release that the SWT Browser is using with a patched release, or you can wait for an updated Eclipse.  Warning: replacing webkit could produce unanticipated side effects.